# Percentage sign in column centered about decimal point

Tags: siunitx

I know how to centre a column about the decimal point using the siunitx package. How do I include a percent sign in the column heading, ie "Heading (%)"? Neither \% or \SI{}{\percent} seem to work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {\cdot}}
    \begin{tabular}{S}
        \hline
        \\ \hline
        3.93  \\ \hline
        3.3  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would use `{Heading (\si{\percent})}` (outer braces to protect it from being recognized as a numerical entry in the column).

Comment: Correct answer is provided by above comment from @PaulGessler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{Heading (\si{\percent})}`. The outer braces are to protect the heading from being recognized as a numerical entry that `siunitx` would otherwise attempt to align.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {\cdot}}
    \begin{tabular}{S}
        \hline
        {Heading (\si{\percent})} \\ \hline
        3.93  \\ \hline
        3.3  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As noted in a comment by daleif, the brace group is not always sufficient for protecting the header contents. In some situations (namely, where the `@{}`, `!{}`, `>{}`, or `<{}` constructs from the `array` package have been used), `\multicolumn{1}{c}{<header content>}` is required instead.

Comment: Note also that in some cases, the `{...}` header feature is actually not good enough, in which case a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` is a better choice (just left here as a future reference).

Comment: @daleif thanks for this note, I added a mention of it to the answer.